# WKWebView Basic auth pop-up appears twice and app crushes

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add basic auth feature to my iOS app's WKWebView. The basic auth pop-up appears in a right way.
But after I enter the correct information, the pop-up appears once more, and when I enter information again the app crushes. The console says `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Completion handler passed to -[SFSafariViewController.WebViewViewController webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:completionHandler:] was not called'`.
Behind the second pop-up the website contents already shows up, so I think basic auth pop-up is called in a wrong way.
Where should I fix?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    var startUrl = "http://basic-auth-page.com"
    var pageTitle: String?
    var requestUrl: String?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

        if let url = URL(string: startUrl) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }

    // open "target_blank" link
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {

        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        }
        return nil
    }

    // for basic auth
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication Required", message: "This is an alert.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
        alertController.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Username"
            usernameTextField = textField
        }
        weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
        alertController.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Password"
            textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
            passwordTextField = textField
        }
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log In", style: .default, handler: { action in
            let credential = URLCredential(user: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
        }))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func prevBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if webView.canGoBack {
            webView.goBack()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if webView.canGoForward {
            webView.goForward()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func refreshBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        webView.reloadFromOrigin()
    }

    @IBAction func doneBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let initialBoard = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "initialBoard")
        self.present(initialBoard, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

===edit===
I found another console warning log when the second pop-up appeared.
`Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fa46d88a600>  on <SFSafariViewController.WebViewViewController: 0x7fa46f10b350> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x7fa46e819000>`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your web view callback to this:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still have the error.   Maybe it's not the problem of basic auth, but of handling UIAlertController. Now The pop-up appears even on normal (= no basic auth feature) page